# Wrap title with dynamic url

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm using the Jade templating engine and I can't seem to get the syntax correct.
I am trying to make a post title link back to it's original source with no luck.

```
div.title= a(href =#Entry.url) #Entry.title
```

The data is pull from the DB fine and it renders in view indiviually, however when I try to nest the url to become the href for the title it breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `{}`

```
a(href="#{Entry.url}") #{Entry.title}
```